# dll.config not copied to temporary asp.net files folder

Tags: asp.net, configurationmanager

I have an Web.Api application that uses functions from a different assembly. For this assembly I have created a .config file where I store some strings.

I am using the following code which should fetch one of those strings:

```
private static string LogUrl = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).AppSettings.Settings["WebApi-LogUrl"].Value.ToString();
```

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` points to temporary asp.net files, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dc2fa3d4\834ee436\assembly\dl3\cd068512) but my dll.config file is not copied there. 
The result is that I cant debug my application and it also gives null when running the code on a real IIS server.

If I set a break point just before getting the setting I can get hold of the temporary folder, and when I copy my dll.config file there it all works, but how should I make do that automatically.

I have the properties for my dll.config file set as "Build action: content", "Copy to output directory: always"

Any help would be appreciated, have googled for hours now. :(

Best regards, 
Peter Larsson!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this by using the following code:

```
// The dllPath can't just use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location as ASP.NET doesn't copy the config to shadow copy path
var dllPath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath;
var dllConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(dllPath);

// Get the appSettings section
var appSettings = (AppSettingsSection) dllConfig.GetSection("appSettings");
return appSettings.Settings;
```

The key there is:

```
new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath
```

I came up with that solution after reading [Zhaph - Ben Duguid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33051/zhaph-ben-duguid)'s answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434339/103778.

Now I'm able to pick up my DLL's configuration file that is in the `bin` directory of my web app.

I have since [written up a blog post](https://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/10/21/dude-wheres-my-dll-config/) discussing this further.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I also noticed that the call to GetName() is useless as the property CodeBase is also a property of the class Assembly.

Comment: LIFESAVER! How much i looked for a solution to this problem. Followed so many suggestions that didn't work. Maybe for google results: I have a DLL with a database connection using Entity Framework and connectionstring is in dll.config.